# Adding a variable into a path inside an array

Tags: php

Is it possible to add a variable into the line in bold?

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            **'path'          => '/csgo',         // path to files (REQUIRED)**
            'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'accessControl' => 'access'             // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);
```

changing it to this did not help

```
'path'          => ".$folder./csgo",         // path to files (REQUIRED)
```

thank you

Comment: Investigate [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
'path' => "$folder/csgo"
```

A slightly better way:

```
'path' => "{$folder}/csgo"
```

This clearly shows the separation of the variable from the string